# Unable to run taurus tests in jenkins. Build console log says bzt command not found

Tags: python, jenkins, jmeter, yaml, taurus

I am trying to run Jmeter tests with the help of taurus in jenkins with performance plugin. In my yml file I have passed the scenarios to run jmx scripts and in jenkins I am using execute shell to run my tests

```
 bzt test_suite.yml -report
```

I have also set the current directory as my workspace in jenkins. So, when I build the project in build console I get the following output

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\muhammad.taus\PycharmProjects\PerfAutomationFramework
[PerfAutomationFramework] $ sh -xe C:\Users\MUHAMM~1.TAU\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins2737910596558040446.sh
+ bzt test_suite.yml -report
C:\Users\MUHAMM~1.TAU\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins2737910596558040446.sh: line 2: bzt: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Creating parser with percentiles:'0,50,90,100,' filterRegex:
Cannot detect file type because of error: Failed to copy C:\Users\muhammad.taus\PycharmProjects\PerfAutomationFramework\stats.xml to C:\Users\muhammad.taus\.jenkins\jobs\PerformanceAutomation\builds\36\temp\stats.xml
Finished: FAILURE
```

But previously the tests used to run fine on my host. I installed taurus using pip and in CMD When I type **bzt** it gets taurus, also when I type **py** it picks python and also I have setup JMETER_HOME and in cmd when I used **jmeter** it opens Jmeter. I am not sure what happened but I am not able to execute the tests anymore. The only thing I remember is changing python version from 32 bit to 64 bit, But I am sure that is not causing the problem. Please if anyone can help me in this regard it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird mix of Linux and Windows and your question doesn't contain sufficient level of details in order to troubleshoot the issue.

1. Use the full path to `python` executable in your shell script
2. Instead of `bzt` use `/path/to/python -m bzt.cli your_config.yml`
3. If you get `No module named bzt` install it using pip:

   ```
   python -m pip install bzt
   ```
4. If `python` executable is not found, try `python3` instead

More information:

- [Installing and Upgrading Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/)
- [Integrating Taurus with Jenkins](https://gettaurus.org/kb/Jenkins/)
- [How to Run Taurus with the Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-taurus-jenkins-performance-plugin)

Comment: Thank you it was indeed the path issue somehow Jenkins could not pick path to python as I switched from 32-bit to 64-bit something weird happened because of the switching. I  simply re-installed python